# Spade in FlowJo v10.0

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have an issue with installing the spade package in R:

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Bioconductor version 3.7 (BiocInstaller 1.30.0), ?biocLite for help
> biocLite("spade")
BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor 3.7 (BiocInstaller 1.30.0), R 3.5.1 (2018-07-02).
Installing package(s) ‘spade’
Old packages: 'foreign', 'survival'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
n
Warning message:
package ‘spade’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1) 
>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZRlX.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to add the relevant code. Nobody can answer this! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely related to the fact that spade appears in the list of packages removed at BioConductor version 3.4. See:
https://bioconductor.org/about/removed-packages/

Trying to install the latest version of `spade_1.8.0` into R 3.5.1 fails because it depends on another abandoned package `igraph0`. `igraph0` has bee replaced by `igraph`. Since `igraph` has substantial differences from `igraph0`, you would probably need to identify all the use of that package and rewrite the package code and then install locally.

The other puzzle is that you chose not to update the packages the installer script identified as missing. That didn't make a difference in this case (and it was a misleading message anyway), but it's not a practice I would recommend in the future.